# Eq Ord Classes Haskell Data

Tags: haskell

Now I have another problem:

Another subtask tells me to derive a data type from the classes.

I don't know how to compare it. Do you have an idea and could you explain it to me so that I can understand?

``

instance Eq where
...

instance Ord where
...

Comment: It isn't clear how you are planning to compare dollars to yens. Should your program fetch exchange rates from the internet or something?

Comment: Your edit makes the question barely meaningful, and certainly divorces it from the answers already given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the way to approach this kind of problem is to not get over-distracted by the type class machinery.  I suggest you start by writing a function like `eqCurrency`:

```hs
eqCurrency :: Currency -> Currency -> Bool
eqCurrency ...
```

The obvious next step is to put in your arguments and do some pattern matching.  For example, I'd probably write:

```hs
eqCurrency :: Currency -> Currency -> Bool
eqCurrency (Dollar d1 c1) (Dollar d2 c2) = ... 
eqCurrency (Yen y1) (Yen y2) = ...
eqCurrency (Euro d1 c1) (Euro d2 c2) = ...
```

Next, you have to decide how to check equality for different types of currency.  So, ask yourself, is there ever a case where some dollar amount can equal some yen amount?  If so, write cases for that.  If not, perhaps you can just add a catch-all pattern match like

```hs
eqCurrency _c1 _c2 = False
```

Once you've written this function and are happy with its behavior, you can slot it in to the type class:

```hs
instance Eq Currency where
  (==) = eqCurrency
```

You'll need to do the same thing for the `Ord` type class.  For `Ord`, [the minimal complete definition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Ord) is either defining `<=` or `compare`, so you should choose one of those.  For instance, you could define:

```hs
leqCurrency :: Currency -> Currency -> Bool
leqCurrency ...
```

Once again, you'll ask yourself the same questions: If I have two `Dollar` amounts, when is one less than the other?  If I have a `Euro` and a `Yen`, which one is less than the other?  I can't answer these semantic questions for you, but you'll use your answers to encode the various cases, and when you're finished, you can fill in the type class:

```hs
instance Ord Currency where
  (<=) = leqCurrency
```

Comment: I think you have a typo -- in the final code block, `Eq` should be `Ord`

Comment: Yes, thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know how to compare each currency

Me neither. "How should currencies be compared" is more of a question of design than of implementation.

If you want to go for full correctness, you'd have to use the internet to download current exchange rates in order to do the comparison. But `Eq` and `Ord` instances simply don't allow internet connection, so that's not really possible.

It sounds like this is for an exercise, so perhaps it'd be fair to choose some fixed exchange rates for your program? Google tells me that, at the time of writing, one US cent is worth 1.4 Yen, so I'll go with that.

Then we know one case for ord:

```
instance Ord Currency where
  compare (Dollar dollars cents) (Yen yen) = compare ((dollars*100 + cents) * 1.4) yen
  -- ...
```

The rest of the `Ord` instance could be filled in in a similar fashion, with cases for `compare (Yen ...) (Dollar ...)` and `compare (Dollar ...) (Euro ...)` etc, etc.

That implementation will work, and would be worth filling out completely.

There is a "cleaner" solution, though, if you're interested. We can choose some "anchor" currency, say Yen. Then we can write a so-called 'normalization' function which converts every currency to Yen:

```
normalize :: Currency -> Integer
normalize (Dollar dollars cents) = (dollars*100 + cents) * 1.4
-- you fill in the rest
```

Using this, we can write `Ord` more simply as just

```
instance Ord Currency where
  compare c1 c2 = compare (normalize c1) (normalize c2)
```